# Заполнение Google Sheets в Telegram bot в цикле

Tags: telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, казалось бы проблема простая, но решения в других ЯП почему то в google script не прокатывают.

Задача: организовать общение с ботом в телеграме и на основе ответов заполнять таблицу в Google Sheets (Гугл Таблицах), по столбцам или строкам. То есть, условно: набираю сообщение "Начать" и после этого бот посылает мне определенный текст, а мои ответы заносит в определенный строку-столбец и так несколько раз. Чтобы заполнить пять значений в таблице нужно дождаться от бота 5 сообщений и 5 раз на них ответить. Привожу код:

```
function telegram(method, params) {
  var token = "XXX--XXX"
  var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/" + method;
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'method': 'post', 'payload': params});
}

function setWebHook () {
  var resp = telegram("setWebhook", {"url": "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX--XXX/exec"});
  Logger.log(resp);
}

// kol_iter = 5;

function doPost(e) {

  var chatList = [XXX--XXX];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  //for (var i = 0; i < kol_iter; i++) {

  var msg = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var newVal;
  newVal = msg.message.text;
  sheet.getRange(now.getDate() + 1, 9).setFormula(newVal);


//  if (nom_iter == 1) 
//    sheet.getRange(now.getDate() + 1, 10).setFormula(newVal);


//  if (nom_iter == 2) 
//    sheet.getRange(now.getDate() + 1, 11).setFormula(newVal);

//}

}
```

Насколько я понимаю, одно сообщение боту -> одно вхождение в функцию doPost. Пробовал создать глобальную переменную с количеством итераций, и на каждое вхождение в doPost инкрементировать переменную, говорящую о том, что первое значение в таблице заполнено. Тогда каждая итерация вхождения в функцию заполняла бы одно значение в ячейке (попробовал отобразить и закомментировать в виде переменных nom_iter - номер итерации, kol_iter - количество итераций).
Но глобальные переменные, которые работали бы в С тут не получаются.

В общем, прошу помощи натолкнуть меня на правильные мысли. Так то задача кажется простой, всего лишь общение без дополнительных требований, но разобраться не получается

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создайте логику в doPost(), далее в функции message_() обрабатывайте текст который приходит.

```
function doPost(e) {
    
    const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    
    if (contents.message) { 
      var chat_id = contents.message.chat.id;
      var from_chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
      var text = contents.message.text;
      var first_name = contents.message.from.first_name;
      var message_id = contents.message.message_id;
   
      message_(chat_id, from_chat_id, text, message_id, first_name);
        
      }
}

message_(chat_id, from_chat_id, text, message_id, first_name) {

// здесь обрабатывайте текст и команды которые присылает бот

}
```